# Error on building Openembedded for Intel Quark

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, cflags

Trying to build Linux for Advantech UBC-221 that has Intel Quark processor.
The system is Debian 9, running on VMware. Was able to build poky succefully before.

Let me summarize what I was doing:

```
mkdir quark
cd quark
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-intel-quark
git clone git://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky
cp -r poky/bitbake .
cd openembedded-core
source oe-init-build-env
bitbake-layers add-layer ~/quark/meta-intel-quark/
bitbake core-image-base
```

Error code I get:

```
WARNING: Layer quark-bsp should set LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_quark-bsp in its conf/layer.conf file to list the core layer names it is compatible with.
WARNING: Layer quark-bsp should set LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_quark-bsp in its conf/layer.conf file to list the core layer names it is compatible with.
WARNING: /home/bgabor/quark/meta-intel-quark/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto-quark_3.8.bb: Variable key RDEPENDS_${KERNEL_PACKAGE_NAME}-base (${KERNEL_PACKAGE_NAME}-image) replaces original key RDEPENDS_kernel-base ().
WARNING: /home/bgabor/quark/meta-intel-quark/recipes-bsp/grub/grub_0.97.bb: Exception during build_dependencies for CFLAGS
WARNING: /home/bgabor/quark/meta-intel-quark/recipes-bsp/grub/grub_0.97.bb: Error during finalise of /home/bgabor/quark/meta-intel-quark/recipes-bsp/grub/grub_0.97.bb
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /home/bgabor/quark/meta-intel-quark/recipes-bsp/grub/grub_0.97.bb
Traceback (most recent call last):
bb.data_smart.ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable CFLAGS, expression was  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/bgabor/quark/openembedded-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/i586-oe-linux/grub/0.97+gitAUTOINC+5775f32a62-r0=/usr/src/debug/grub/0.97+gitAUTOINC+5775f32a62-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/bgabor/quark/openembedded-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/i586-oe-linux/grub/0.97+gitAUTOINC+5775f32a62-r0/recipe-sysroot= -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/bgabor/quark/openembedded-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/i586-oe-linux/grub/0.97+gitAUTOINC+5775f32a62-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=  -Os -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Werror -Wno-shadow -Wno-unused  -Wno-pointer-sign  -DINTEL_QUARK_TEST=${@base_contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'grub_test', '1', '0', d)} which triggered exception NameError: name 'base_contains' is not defined
Summary: There were 5 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm pretty much stuck here. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
Tried to build on Debian 7.11 32 bit system. It went better however another error came:

```
bgabor@debian:~/quark/dizzy/build$ bitbake core-image-base
WARNING: Host distribution "Debian-7.11" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution.
Loading cache: 100% |####################################################################################################################################################| ETA:  00:00:00
Loaded 1292 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.24.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "i686-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Debian-7.11"
TARGET_SYS        = "i586-poky-linux"
MACHINE           = "quark"
DISTRO            = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "1.7.3"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "m32 i586"
TARGET_FPU        = ""
meta              
meta-yocto        
meta-yocto-bsp    = "dizzy:58863ad092c9a279e305c841dbb4353de2ecfae8"
meta-intel-quark  = "master:a314f0ceea986fde42d5d9b0ea449f7a563e9351"

NOTE: Preparing runqueue
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: Unable to install packages. Command '/home/bgabor/quark/dizzy/build/tmp/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/bin/smart --quiet --data-dir=/home/bgabor/quark/dizzy/build/tmp/work/quark-poky-linux/core-image-minimal-initramfs/1.0-r0/rootfs/var/lib/smart install -y busybox@i586 initramfs-live-install-efi@i586 run-postinsts@all initramfs-live-install@i586 udev@i586 initramfs-live-boot@quark base-passwd@i586' returned 1:
error: Can't install initramfs-live-install-1.0-r9@i586: no package provides grub

ERROR: Function failed: do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/bgabor/quark/dizzy/build/tmp/work/quark-poky-linux/core-image-minimal-initramfs/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.29435
ERROR: Task 240 (/home/bgabor/quark/dizzy/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal-initramfs.bb, do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2529 tasks of which 2527 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
No currently running tasks (2435 of 2531)

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/bgabor/quark/dizzy/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal-initramfs.bb, do_rootfs
Summary: There was 1 WARNING message shown.
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

It does not find grub package, however I can see there are two in the recipes:

```
bgabor@debian:~/quark/dizzy/build$ bitbake-layers show-recipes | grep "grub" -A 3
Parsing recipes..done.
grub:
  meta-intel-quark     0.97+gitAUTOINC+5775f32a62
  meta                 0.97
  meta                 2.00
--
grub-conf:
  meta-intel-quark     1.0
grub-efi:
  meta                 2.00
gsettings-desktop-schemas:
  meta                 3.10.1
```

Tried to clean and then bitbake again but no result.
What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Poky includes OpenEmbedded Core so you don't need to clone both, just clone Poky.

Second, the meta-intel-iot layer is pretty dead and only formally supports the Daisy release of Poky (see the README).  You may have luck using newer releases, but obviously not git master (aka Thud).

https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Releases lists the releases.  Instead of checking out master of Poky, check out the relevant release branch.  I suggest starting with daisy but trying something a little newer such as jethro would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the infos!
Trying the build with host system Debian 8.11 x86 and with Poky dizzy build.
It's halfway done now, not showing any errors (yet).
It seems like it is really sensitive to what host distro you are building on.

Comment: Build failed unfortunately, retried with other host. Added some more info after "Edit:"